# Visual Studio Xamarin app: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:keyboardNavigationCluster'

Tags: xamarin.android

I am using Visual Studio 2017 trying to compile a Xamarin app I got from a repo and I get the following error and don't know how to get VS configured correctly to get rid of this compile error:

Error: No resource found that matches the given name: Error     \Source\app-office-locator\src\Droid\obj\Debug\lp\49\jl\res\values-v26\values-v26.xml:1: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:keyboardNavigationCluster'. OfficeLocator.Droid C:\Source\app-office-locator\src\Droid\C

Comment: Could you please tell us which repo you are using ?

Comment: @york-shen-msft, this problem is solved.  The issue was that Xamarin SDK Manager was not installed so even though Android Studio installed Oreo, Visual Studio would not show it or link to it and that is where the missing resource lived so as soon as I was able to Target Oreo the problem was resolved.